# Ansible warning about boolean type conversion

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, vagrant

I have this snippet of Ansible:

```
  - name: check for reboot request
    stat:
      path: /var/run/reboot-required
    register: reboot_request

  - name: reboot if requested
    reboot:
      reboot_timeout: 180
      test_command: whoami
    when: reboot_request.stat.exists
```

...which generates this warning:

```
[WARNING]: The value True (type bool) in a string field was converted to
u'True' (type string). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the
entire value to ensure it does not change.
```

I find the error message not super-helpful.  What would be the proper syntax?

I am running Ansible 2.9.7 on MacOS 10.15.4 and the target machine is Ubuntu 18.04.3 built with Vagrant 2.2.7, if any of that matters!  :)

EDIT: Here is my whole playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Ubuntu Update and Upgrade 
    apt:
      upgrade: yes
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600

  - name: check for reboot request
    stat:
      path: /var/run/reboot-required
    register: reboot_request

  - name: reboot if requested
    reboot:
      reboot_timeout: 180
      test_command: whoami
    when: reboot_request.stat.exists
```

Comment: It seems like your question is incomplete; you will want to include more of the error message you are actually experiencing, because that playbook does not generate any such warning on 2.9.7 locally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the issue is here

```
  - name: Ubuntu Update and Upgrade 
    apt:
      upgrade: yes
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600
```

If you look at the apt documentation (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html) you fill find that the `upgrade` key needs a string not a bool.

```
Choices:
dist
full
no ←
safe
yes
```

So you have to write this

```
  - name: Ubuntu Update and Upgrade 
    apt:
      upgrade: "yes"
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600
```

To remove the warning

Comment: Yep!  That was the fix.  I totally misinterpreted the message.  Apparently it applied to the playbook and was displayed at the end of the playbook execution, which got me running completely down the wrong track.  Sure would be nice if the message indicated which statement it had issues with!

Comment: @guest then please accept papey's answer, to help others know that is the correct fix